# php post and redirect page same time

Tags: php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am not php expert but i get stuck here. I have following three `.php` files

1. index.php  <- drop down list, which select DB table.
2. query.php  <- it craft json query.
3. chart.php  <- it's highchart JQuery page. which use `$.getJSON("query.php", function(json) {`  function to fetch data from `query.php` file.

`index.php` will get user input from drop-down list of select DB/Table and pass it to `query.php` and set `SELECT * FROM $table` variable.

But i want to do `POST` and at same time it will open `chart.php` page so i can direct redirect to chart page. How i send POST and Redirect same time so `query.php` get $table variable and instantly `chart.php` open chart.

## EDIT:

If i put all my `query.php` code inside `chart.php` then how do i put those json values in `$.getJSON()` ?

```
$.getJSON("query.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                options.series[2] = json[3];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
```

how `$.getJSON()` will get value from variable?

Comment: Can you try it with the `success` even of each action in jquery itself ?

Comment: You could either change your code to save the posted value to a `$_SESSION` value OR post the form/value directly to `chart.php` and add it as a param in your `$.getJSON ()`

Comment: @Sean - I like you second idea but how do i put `json` output values in `$.getJSON()` function? see i have edited my question

Comment: Add it to your url `$.getJSON("query.php?data=<?php echo $_POST['yourDropdownName']; ?>", function(json) {...`. Then in `query.php` change to `$_GET ['data']` to get the selected ddropdown option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) from index.php -> make POST request to chart.php with needed parameters

2) using $_POST on chart.php => receive data from index.php and show on template like :

for GET request to query.php

```
$.getJSON("query.php?<?='param1='.$_POST['param1']?>", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                options.series[2] = json[3];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
```

or using usual $.ajax request send via POST request:

```
$.ajax({ 
         url: 'query.php',
         data: "<?='param1='.$_POST['param1']?>"
         dataType : "json",
         method:"POST",
         success: function(json){
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                options.series[2] = json[3];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

If your server don't have short_open_tag=On - use `<?php echo 'param1='.$_POST['param1'] ?>`

And check params before giving them on template

Comment: in `query.php` i am trying to embed `$_GET[param1]` in `SQL` query but it didn't work, am i doing it right? `$query = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(AcctStartTime, '%d %b') AS Days, SUM(SipResponseCode LIKE '2%') AS '2xx', SUM(SipResponseCode LIKE '4%') AS '4xx' , SUM(SipResponseCode LIKE '5%') AS '5xx' FROM '" . $_GET["param1"] ."' GROUP BY DATE(AcctStartTime);") or die ("Dadasdad");`

Comment: Nevermind, I figure out how to pass variable to `sql` query, Thanks